# strange behavior of eigen::select()

Tags: c++, eigen

in eigen, the construct:

```
(R.array() < s).select(P,Q);
```

works when either one or both of P,Q are vectors 
(of the same length as R). But as soon as both 
of them are scalars, I get a compilation error.

My question is; is the behavior of `select` in the presence 
of two scalars a way for eigen to warn me that 
there are more efficient constructs? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can workaround by using `VectorXd::Constant(size,value)` for one argument.

Comment: yes, that's what I did. But I was wondering if by throwing a warning eigen was 'trying' to tell me that I'm not using the best construct for the job...

Comment: Nope, it's just that this shortcut does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please ref the definition of select() in Eigen: 
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a65e78cfcbc9852e6923bebff4323ddca

[image]