# Eigen: how can I substitute matrix positive values with 1 and 0 otherwise?

Tags: matlab, eigen, eigen3

I want to write the following matlab code in `Eigen` (where `K` is `pxp` and `W` is `pxb`):

```
H = (K*W)>0;
```

However the only thing that I came up so far is:

```
H = ((K*W.array() > 0).select(1,0));
```

This code doesn't work as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440511/strange-behavior-of-eigenselect), but replacing `0` with `VectorXd::Constant(p,0)` (as suggested in the link question) generates a runtime error:

```
Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<T, Value>::variable_if_dynamic(T) [with T = long int; int Value = 1]: Assertion `v == T(Value)' failed.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `.select()`. You just need to cast an array of `bool` to an array of `H`'s component type.

```
H = ((K * W).array() > 0.0).cast<double>();
```

---

Your original attempt failed because the size of your constant 1/0 array is not match with the size of `H`. Using `VectorXd::Constant` is not a good choice when `H` is `MatrixXd`. You also have a problem with parentheses. I think you want `*` rather than `.*` in matlab notation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
  const int p = 5;
  const int b = 10;
  MatrixXd H(p, b), K(p, p), W(p, b);
  K.setRandom();
  W.setRandom();
  H = ((K * W).array() > 0.0).cast<double>();
  std::cout << H << std::endl << std::endl;

  H = ((K * W).array() > 0).select(MatrixXd::Constant(p, b, 1),
                                   MatrixXd::Constant(p, b, 0));
  std::cout << H << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

When calling a template member function in a template, you need to use the `template` keyword.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
using namespace Eigen;

template<typename Mat, typename Vec>
void createHashTable(const Mat &K, Eigen::MatrixXi &H, Mat &W, int b) {
  Mat CK = K;
  H = ((CK * W).array() > 0.0).template cast<int>();
}

int main() {
  const int p = 5;
  const int b = 10;
  Eigen::MatrixXi H(p, b);
  Eigen::MatrixXf W(p, b), K(p, p);
  K.setRandom();
  W.setRandom();
  createHashTable<Eigen::MatrixXf, Eigen::VectorXf>(K, H, W, b);
  std::cout << H << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

See this for some explanation.

[Issue casting C++ Eigen::Matrix types via templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754251/issue-casting-c-eigenmatrix-types-via-templates)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wouldn't be even better `.cast<int>()`?

Comment: "depending on `H`'s type". As you did not specify `H`'s type, I assume it is `MatrixXd`

Comment: Thanks. However I get this compile error:
`../Math.hpp:82:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  H = ((CK*W).array()>0.0).cast<int>();
                                ^
../Math.hpp:82:32: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’`

Comment: Can you show a full code example like mine so I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Updated with the full code. I posted it all since I don't know where the error could be and I don't want to forget the main error point

Comment: Too many things unkown like `Mat` and how you call your function. Maybe you can modify my code and reproduce your problem, starting from `#include` to `return 0;`

Comment: Updated, sorry if this is getting so much of your time :(

Comment: But the first solution (using select) compile and works correctly

Comment: @justHelloWorld see update. you need to use `.template cast<int>()`